# Discord.js: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm having my first go at making a Discord bot. The code is very basic, just a bot that logs its own tag into the console upon startup:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const TOKEN = "REDACTED"

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
})

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Upon typing `node index.js` into the VSCode terminal, however, I am given the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\15055\Documents\Alt Formatter> node index.js
C:\Users\15055\Documents\Alt Formatter\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:168
    throw new RangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
    ^

RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS.
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (C:\Users\15055\Documents\Alt Formatter\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:168:11)
    at C:\Users\15055\Documents\Alt Formatter\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:163:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (C:\Users\15055\Documents\Alt Formatter\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:163:40)
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\15055\Documents\Alt Formatter\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:481:41)
    at new Client (C:\Users\15055\Documents\Alt Formatter\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\15055\Documents\Alt Formatter\index.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 11
}

Node.js v18.4.0
```

I have installed discord.js with the command `npm i discord.js` so I'm using v14.

Comment: I've just tested your code in both v12 and v13 of discord.js and there was no error at all, worked as expected.

Comment: Please change your token as you have leaked it!

Comment: Please make sure, you refresh your token as it's exposed in your last edit!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In discord.js v14, intent flags are available from `GatewayIntentBits`.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
  ]
})
```

List of changes:

| v12/v13 | v14 |
| --- | --- |
| `GUILDS` | `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds` |
| `GUILD_BANS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans` |
| `GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers` |
| `GUILD_INTEGRATIONS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations` |
| `GUILD_INVITES` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites` |
| `GUILD_MEMBERS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers` |
| `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions` |
| `GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping` |
| `GUILD_MESSAGES` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages` |
| `GUILD_PRESENCES` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences` |
| `GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENTS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildScheduledEvents` |
| `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates` |
| `GUILD_WEBHOOKS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks` |
| `DIRECT_MESSAGES` | `GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages` |
| `DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING` | `GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping` |
| `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` | `GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions` |
| N/A | `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` |

Answer (score 0):

the solution I've found based on the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents) is :

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    ]});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

Based [on the documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents), you can't use strings for intent names, but you import them from the package, so in your case something like

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
  Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
]});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did try doing this before using strings, and it throws the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\15055\Documents\Alt Formatter\index.js:10:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
    ...............

Comment: Using strings for intent names works perfectly fine. @Arman what version of DJs are you using?

Comment: I ran npm install discord.js whilst in my project directory only a couple of hours ago. Should be the latest version, it says up to date.