# "GUILD" intent throwing error (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i am trying to make a discord bot but when i use this code i get an error. please help, as i do not understand!

EDIT: i just attached the error, you're welcome!

code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({
    allowedMentions: {
        parse: ['users', 'roles'],
        repliedUser: true
    },
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES",
        "GUILD_PRESENCES",
        "GUILD_MEMBERS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"
    ],
});
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('I am ready')
});
client.login("TOKEN")
```

error is:

```
C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\code\js\my bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:168
    throw new RangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
    ^

RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\code\js\my bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:168:11)
    at C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\code\js\my bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:163:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\code\js\my bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:163:40)
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\code\js\my bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:481:41)
    at new Client (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\code\js\my bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\code\js\my bot\index.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 11
}
```

Comment: please show us the error as well.

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: i think the newest one? @ZsoltMeszaros

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js: Invalid bitfield flag or number: GUILDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73018560/discord-js-invalid-bitfield-flag-or-number-guilds)

Answer (score 1):

In discord.js v14, intent flags are available from `GatewayIntentBits`.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
  ],
});
```

List of changes:

| v12/v13 | v14 |
| --- | --- |
| `GUILDS` | `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds` |
| `GUILD_BANS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans` |
| `GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers` |
| `GUILD_INTEGRATIONS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations` |
| `GUILD_INVITES` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites` |
| `GUILD_MEMBERS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers` |
| `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions` |
| `GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping` |
| `GUILD_MESSAGES` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages` |
| `GUILD_PRESENCES` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences` |
| `GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENTS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildScheduledEvents` |
| `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates` |
| `GUILD_WEBHOOKS` | `GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks` |
| `DIRECT_MESSAGES` | `GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages` |
| `DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING` | `GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping` |
| `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` | `GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions` |
| N/A | `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` |

Comment: I know it's generally discouraged to comment "thanks!" type comments onto posts, but I really did want to say thank you for creating this table because it is extremely helpful and I hadn't found it in the discord.js "Updating from v13 to v14" guide.

Answer (score 0):

They're PascalCase in the newest version. So `Guilds` not `GUILDS`